# How to fetch list by match userType and verification status in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm Creating a app in which i'm trying to fetch Users List by matching their designation and verification status. If verification status is 0 then it will nothing but if verification status is 1 in database(and matching designation also)then it have to fetch that user in the List. I tried to fetch list by matching designation of user, it works properly but when i'm trying to match its Verification Status then app is going crash.

My Code for fetching list.

```
    mUsersList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.advrecyclerview);
    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mUsersDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    mUsersDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);



}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    //mUsersDatabaseReference.child(uid).child("online").setValue("true");

    //-------FIREBASE RECYCLE VIEW ADAPTER-------

    mUsersDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String verifiedStatus = dataSnapshot.child("VerificationStatus").getValue().toString();

            if (verifiedStatus.equals("1")){
                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserViewHolder>(
                        Users.class,
                        R.layout.recycle_list_single_user,
                        AdvTalkActivity.UserViewHolder.class, mUsersDatabaseReference.orderByChild("designation").equalTo("ADVOCATE")){
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(final AdvTalkActivity.UserViewHolder viewHolder, final Users users, final int position) {

                        viewHolder.setName(users.getName());
                        viewHolder.setStatus(users.getStatus());
                        viewHolder.setdesignation(users.getDesignation());
                        viewHolder.setImage(users.getThumb_image(), getApplicationContext());
                        final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();



                        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(AdvTalkActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                                startActivity(profileIntent);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                };
                mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            SweetToast.error(AdvTalkActivity.this, "Unknown Error...");
        }
    });



}

public static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView userNameView=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleListName);
        userNameView.setText(name);
    }


    public void setStatus(String status) {
        TextView userStatusView=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleListStatus);
        userStatusView.setText(status);
    }

    public void setImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx) {
        CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageViewUserImage);
        //Log.e("thumb URL is--- ",thumb_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.avtarr).into(userImageView);
    }
    public void setdesignation(String designation){

        TextView userStatusView=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleListDesignation);
        userStatusView.setText(designation);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    //String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    //mUsersDatabaseReference.child(uid).child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    super.onStop();
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `onDataChange` dataSnapshot has no direct child with `VerificationStatus`. That's why it causing exception.

Actually `dataSnapshot` contains list of user object. So, first of all you have to parse user from that and then do operation on user object.

Try to use `orderByChild("VerificationStatus").equalTo("1")` to get only the user who is verified.

```
mUsersDatabaseReference.orderByChild("VerificationStatus").equalTo("1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Users user = child.getValue(Users.class);
            if(user.getDesignation().equalsIgnoreCase("ADVOCATE")) {
                //Do your operation here
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        SweetToast.error(AdvTalkActivity.this, "Unknown Error...");
    }
});
```

Comment: But i have to fetch those who are verified and whose userType match also

Comment: Add your user model also

Comment: where i have to add it ?.  At the time of verification status check or in designation check?

Comment: Check my updated solution. You did your operation on wrong object

Comment: Don't forgot to handle multiple user if you have multiple user with `VerificationStatus = "1" `and  `designation = "ADVOCATE"`

Comment: @Chauhan, did you try this?

Comment: Yes i tried this. It solved my problem but now i have done it with different way.

Comment: If it help you then accept the answer and press upvote so that others can find it helpful. Thanks